# SSIS Can't Store Decimal Output Into Variable (Execute SQL Task)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

For the life of me I can't figure out how to store a decimal from a Stored Procedure into an SSIS Variable.

I have an Execute SQL Task that returns a result set. I mapped the column to the variable. I keep getting "Input string was not in a correct format". If I'm returning a decimal from my stored procedure and have the variable type as decimal. I would think this would work, but it doesn't.

Other things I've tried...
- Cast the column as a float and use variable double.
- Cast the column as a varchar and use variable string (succeeded but didn't store value)
- I've done variations on using Output instead of resultset but basically same issues.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Thanks in advance!

As requested here are some screenshots:
This shows the assignment to the variable.
[image]

This is showing the variable as a decimal type.
[image]

This is showing the error received.
[image]

I didn't include the stored procedure but it defines vPreviousValue as a decimal(18,4) and returns it in the result set.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of your set up?  That you are getting an error referring to `strings` when you say the problem is regarding decimal data passing is throwing red flags.

Comment: My first search result may very well be your answer. [SSIS and Stored Procedure OUTPUT - MSDN](http://www.sqlsafety.com/?p=649) are you sure anything is working as desired?

Comment: iamdave - I'll post a couple screenshots in a little bit. Thanks.

 
clifton_h - I am able to do what you linked me _for those fields that are not decimals_. It's only specifically decimal data type that is giving me a hard time storing.

Answer (score 1):

In case it may be helpful to someone else in the future...
After trying many variations I was able to figure out how to make this work.

I had the stored procedure output into a 'double' parameter.

I also found this link useful: http://milambda.blogspot.com/2014/02/sql-server-integration-services-data.html