# SSIS - Input String was not in a correct format SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, resultset

I'm working on a workflow in SSIS and I keep having an error about the result set of one sql task. Here are the info:

From a first table I sum up a field that contain value as such:

```
 3.4;534.3;4.5;12.4;
```

with the following stored proc :

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTotalOfSemiColomnSeperatedVal] 
(
  @semiColomnSeperatedVal varchar(1000)
)
RETURNS decimal(18,2)
AS
BEGIN

declare @sum decimal(18,2)
DECLARE @x XML 
SELECT @x = CAST('<A>'+ REPLACE(@semiColomnSeperatedVal,';','</A><A>')+ '</A>' AS XML)

SELECT @sum=sum(t.value('.', 'decimal(18,2)')) 
  FROM @x.nodes('/A') AS x(t)

return @sum END GO
```

The result is added in a table alongside with other information.
The column (Total) is defined as decimal(18,2).

After that, I'm doing a sum of the Total field for a single combination:

```
select sum(total) 
from mytable
where 
column1= ?
and column2= ?
and column3= ?
and column4= ?
and column5= ?
and column5= ?
and column6= ?
and column7= ?
```

- So that query returns a single value and in the SQL task:

[image: General screen]

In the Result set page:

[image]

The variable VolTotal here is defined as decimal in the Variable screen.

The error I keep getting is 'input string was not in a correct format '

Do you have any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301077/ssis-cant-store-decimal-output-into-variable-execute-sql-task), you have to store your result into a Double variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found that the problem was indeed the fact that my Stored procedure was not returning a float. It was returning a double instead.